# Oracle SQL Developer Database Copy Error

Tags: oracle, copy

I am trying to utilise the database copy in Oracle SQL Developer, specifically the Objects Copy to copy data from a table in one database to the same table in another database.
I am trying to copy data from one table on a database, to the exact same format table on another database. See below for log output.

When doing this I come up with the following error:

```
Copy Option: Objects 
Copy Source Connection: DATABASEA 
Destination Connection: DATABASEB 
DDL Objects: Views Tables Materialized Views 
Data Objects: Tables Table X 
Object Where: PROCESS_DATE = '2017-12-31' 
Copy DDL: No 
Copy Data: Yes 
Append Existing Objects 
--- START 
------------------------------------------------------------‌​-------- 
Skipping Table X 
--- END ------------------------------------------------------------‌​--------–
```

I am following the steps outlined here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r31/DatabaseCopy/DatabaseCopy.html

I was able to perform a data copy before I got a new laptop, using the exact same software.

I would be grateful for any advice on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Where exactly is the error? Can you clarify what you are doing?

Comment: Trying to copy data from one table on a database, to the exact same format table on another database.

See below for log output.

Copy Option: Objects Copy
Source Connection: DATABASEA
Destination Connection: DATABASEB
DDL Objects:
Views
Tables
Materialized Views
Data Objects:
Tables
Table X
Object Where: PROCESS_DATE = '2017-12-31'
Copy DDL: No
Copy Data: Yes
Append Existing Objects
--- START --------------------------------------------------------------------
Skipping Table X
--- END --------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please add **all** relevant information to the question and not using a comment. And as far as I read that message, I see no error.

Comment: Have added the relevant information - the issue is that the copy completes straight away and that no data is copied. These are large tables.

Comment: I've encountered the same issues with SQL Developer v18.4.0.376. The table of interest is skipped straight away without any error message. Instead, some materialized views, which I haven't selected, are being copied.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the root cause of this issue was a previous attempt to copy this table which failed and SQL Developer failed to roll back the changed - even though I selected the "Cancel and rollback" option. As a result, the table was deleted and the second attempt to copy the table data **without DDL** was simply skipped - without any error message or explanation. IMHO, the database or SQL Developer should rather output an error message.

Eventually, I was able to resolve the issue by copying the DDL, too.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the query from teams and then send an email to yourself through outlook by pasting the query in the email. Then copy the same query from outlook and use, it will work fine